# Updating UUPSProxy contract's inherited contract

Tags: solidity, upgrading

I modularized my smart contracts for them to be more manageable, and I am also using `UUPSUpgradeable` pattern in my core contract. Now I have a problem though. Consider following example:

```
contract CoreContract is UUPSUpgradeable, Base {}

contract Base {
  function foo() internal view virtual {}
}
```

I want to be able to override the `Base.foo` method in another version of `CoreContract`. Here is how I can do it:

```
contract CoreContractV2 is CoreContract {
  function foo() internal view override virtual {}
}
```

But this breaks the modularity of my project, because I want method `foo` to be in contract `Base`. Hence, I tried the following:

```
contract CoreContractV2 is CoreContract, BaseV2 {}

contract BaseV2 is Base {
  function foo() internal view override virtual {}
}
```

But it throws an error saying:

```
Derived contract must override function "foo". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
```

Can I achieve what I want, if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to create new contract CoreContractV2 and inherit CoreContract, override or something like that. If you truly know your contracts code, just edit on it and deploy the new, then upgrade.

```
contract CoreContract is UUPSUpgradeable, Base {}

contract Base {
  function foo() internal view virtual {
   // your old code
  }
}
```

Just keep it

=>

```
contract CoreContractV2 is UUPSUpgradeable, Base {}

contract Base {
  function foo() internal view virtual {
   // Your new code
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot. Just to add to the answer, I believe I don't event need to go CoreContractV2. I can just update the code inside Base contract, and upgrade the CoreContract, and it will take place right away.